# Blazor: how can I restrict access to a property in a razor file (razor component)?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a razor file:

```
<div>@GetEmail()</div>
```

And a code behind file:

```
public partial class EmailAddress
{
    [Inject]
    private IOptionsSnapshot<EmailSettings> EmailSettings { get; set; }

    private string GetEmail()
    {
        return EmailSettings.Value.EmailAddress;
    }
}
```

I am injecting "EmailSettings" (there are: EmailAddress, EmailLogin or EmailPassword).
Now a frontend developer can use in the razor file the following code (but I don't want it), he should use only "GetEmail" method:

```
@EmailSettings.Value.EmailAddress
@EmailSettings.Value.EmailLogin
@EmailSettings.Value.EmailPassword
```

But it shouldn't be allowed in the razor file (only allowed in the code behind file). How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question.  What do you mean with "Now everyone can use in the razor file". How can they use it? Who is "everyone"?

Comment: @JHBonarius - I mean a frontend developer who develop a razor page.

Comment: If there are trust issues between backend and frontend developers, you have a serious issue in your company IMHO. You should work together on this. Additionally, I'm hoping you're not storing the password in plaintext...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it shouldn't be allowed in the razor file (only allowed in the code behind file).

That can't be done.

The .razor file and the code-behind file hold 2 sections of the same `partial class`. During compilation they will be merged into 1 class, in IL the distinction is no longer present.

Also, be aware that concepts like `public` and `private` are not about security but about organizing your code (architecture).

> Now a frontend developer can use in the razor file

When you want to prevent that then you will have to split the `EmailSettings` into two or three different classes.
But the code-behind code will see the same restrictions, that can't be helped.